# Keras batch training online predicting not learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have been working on a side project trying to learn machine learning with Keras myself and I think I am stuck here.

My intention is to predict the bike availability of a public sharing system that has 31 stations. For now I am only training my model to predict the availability of one station only. I'd like to do online predictions with batch training. I'd like to start giving it a number of bikes at, for example, `00:00` with N given time steps plus the day of the year and weekday.

The input data is this:

- Day of the year, encoded as ints, 1-JAN is 0, 2-JAN is 1...
- Time in 5' intervals encoded as ints the same way as before, 00:00 is 0, 00:05 is 1...
- Weekday, again encoded as int

Those 3 columns are then normalized, then i add the columns that refer to the bikes, they are one hot encode, if the station has 20 bikes the encoded array will have length 21. The data is then transformed to a supervised problem more or less following [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/) tutorial.

Now I divide my dataset into training (65%) and test (35%) samples. And then define the neural network as this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_neurons, batch_input_shape=(1000, 5, 24), stateful=False))
model.add(Dense(max_cases, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy', 'mse', 'mae'])
```

[image]

Fit the model

```
for i in range(epochs):
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1, batch_size=new_batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()

    w = model.get_weights()
```

[image: Stats]

Accuracy plot looks good but the loss one does weird things.

Once the training finishes I predict values, I change from stateless to stateful and modify the batch size

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_neurons, batch_input_shape=(1, 5, 24), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(max_cases, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy', 'mse', 'mae'])
model.set_weights(w)
```

[image: New model after training]

I now predict using the test values I got from before

```
for i in range(0, len(test_x)):

    auxx = test_x[i].reshape((batch_size, test_x[i].shape[0], test_x[i].shape[1])) # (...,n_in,4)

    yhat = model.predict(auxx, batch_size = batch_size)
```

This is the result, I am zooming it a bit to get  a closer look and not a crowded plot. It doesn't look bad at all, it has some errors but overall the predictions looks good enough.

[image: Train plot zoomed]

After this I create my set of data to do the online prediction and predict

```
for i in range(0,290):

    # ...

    predicted_bikes =  model.predict(data_to_feed, batch_size = 1)

   # ...
```

The result is this one, a continuous line.

[image]

As I've seen in the previous plot the predicted value is moved like an interval later to the real value which makes me think that the neural network has learnt to repeat the previous values. That's why here I got a straight line.

Comment: have you tried training with validation?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the results are the same

Comment: Please could you clarify (1) what does each dimension of `batch_input_shape=(1000, 5, 24)` mean? and (2) what's the rationale behind making the LSTM stateful for online predictions?

Comment: [batch_size, time_steps, features] features are 3 (day of year, weekday, time) and 21 bikes (one hot encoded)